# I am trying to fetch my data from mysql database to android app in a tabular form

Tags: android, mysql

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
TableLayout tl;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tl= (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);

    class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
    {       
        String result = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();                    
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.3/worker2.php");                 
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);                   
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

    is = entity.getContent();                   

                Log.e("log_tag", "connection success");                 

                } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection" + e.toString());                    
                }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            TableLayout tv = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.table);
            tv.removeAllViewsInLayout();
            int flag = 1;
            for (int i = -1; i < jArray.length() - 1; i++) {
            TableRow tr = new TableRow(MainActivity.this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            if (flag == 1) {
            TextView b6 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

            b6.setText("Id");                           
            b6.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);

            b6.setTextSize(15);                         
            tr.addView(b6);

            TextView b19 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);

            b19.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);                            
            b19.setTextSize(15);

            b19.setText("Name");                            
            b19.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            tr.addView(b19);
            TextView b29 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            b29.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b29.setText("Status");
            b29.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
            b29.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b29);

            tv.addView(tr);                         
            final View vline = new View(MainActivity.this);

            vline.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 2));
            vline.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            tv.addView(vline);
            flag = 0;                           
            } 
                    else 
            {   
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            Log.i("log_tag", "id: " + json_data.getInt("Worker_id") + ", Username: " + json_data.getString("Worker_name") + ", No: " + json_data.getString("Nationality"));
            TextView b = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            String stime = String.valueOf(json_data.getInt("Worker_id"));
            b.setText(stime);
            b.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            b.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b);
            TextView b1 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            b1.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            b1.setTextSize(15);
            String stime1 = json_data.getString("Worker_name");
            b1.setText(stime1);
            b1.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tr.addView(b1);
            TextView b2 = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
            b2.setPadding(10, 0, 0, 0);
            String stime2 = json_data.getString("Nationality");
            b2.setText(stime2);
            b2.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            b2.setTextSize(15);
            tr.addView(b2);
            tv.addView(tr);
            final View vline1 = new View(MainActivity.this);
            vline1.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 1));
            vline1.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            tv.addView(vline1);
                    }
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JsonArray fail", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
 DownloadTask dl = new DownloadTask();
dl.execute();
}
```

error

```
10-13 15:21:20.743: E/log_tag(3135): Error in http connectionorg.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://localhost:3307 refused
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135): Process: com.example.inform, PID: 3135
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:92)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:108)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at com.example.inform.MainActivity$1DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:69)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at com.example.inform.MainActivity$1DownloadTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-13 15:21:20.763: E/AndroidRuntime(3135):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you are not interested to respond to the answer then, don't post the questions.
Respond to the given answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem is, given Url is not working properly when I tried to call that link I got the connection timed out error.

The problem might be the given url scope is with in the network(Intra network) or something else  please look at your server configuration whether the url can be accessible at global or not

and
For calling the API HttpClient is not good it's my suggestion, **From api level Marshmallow(23) HttpClient will not support** so better to migrate into HttpUrlConnection
Follow the code from the link

[Calling Php File from android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033644/calling-php-file-in-java-via-url/)