# Calling PHP File in Java via URL

Tags: java, php, android

I'm trying to develop an android app that calls a php file to query and pull data from a database. The URL is accesible on my mobile phone on the web browser, but I can't seem to call it from my java code below. Could anyone assist me in calling my PHP file from my Java code.

```
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.3.2/MYCODE/app/login.php");
            String urlParams = "name="+name+"&password="+password;

            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStream os = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            os.write(urlParams.getBytes());
            os.flush();
            os.close();

            InputStream is = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            while((tmp=is.read())!=-1){
                data+= (char)tmp;
            }

            is.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
```

I get the following error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException:`

I'm using the `POST` method because it's more secure.

Comment: if you not interested to respond to the answer then don't post the questions.

Answer (score 3):

If it's GET method then we can use the below lines of code and the issue with your calling file might be your .php file path is incorrect

```
    //Integrating url with values [Starts]
    Map<String, String> request = new HashMap<String, String>();
    request.put("name", name);
    request.put("password", password);
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = new Uri.Builder();
    uriBuilder.encodedPath("http://10.0.3.2/MYCODE/app/login.php");
    if (mapOfStrings != null) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : request.entrySet()) {
            Log.d("buildSanitizedRequest", "key: " + entry.getKey()
                    + " value: " + entry.getValue());
            uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter(entry.getKey(),
                    entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    String uriString;
    try {
        uriString = uriBuilder.build().toString(); // May throw an
                                                   // UnsupportedOperationException
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "Exception" + e);
    }
    //Integrating url with values [Ends]
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URLuriBuilder.build().toString());
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "utf-8,*");
        Log.d("Get-Request", url.toString());
        try {
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            Log.d("Get-Response", stringBuilder.toString());
            return new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
        } finally {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
        return null;
    }`
```

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure the following 2 lines in Manifest and WIFI is enabled and connected to subnet 10.0.3.x

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

If post method is get, where is "?" in your URL?

Answer (score 0):

you can use in this method`URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test.php?print=success");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.connect();`

same this i have use for one of my project this  cluesshop.com

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.